# PHP - $_POST variables mixing with variables having the same name

Tags: php

On the same page I have

```
$hello = 'Hello!';
$_POST['hello'] = '123';
```

If I echo $hello, instead of getting 'Hello!' I get '123'.
How should I handle variables and $_POST variables with the same name?

This is an example of the real problem:

I have a signup form that looks like this (here's a minified sample of fields).
Each input field has a label and the string variable in the label has the same name as the input.

```
<form id="form1" action="post.php">
  <span class="label"><?=$fullname?></span>
  //$fullname='Please enter your name';
  <input name="fullname" id="fullname" type="text">

  <span class="label"><?=$email?></span>
  //$email='Please enter your email';
  <input name="email" id="email" type="text">

  <input name="button1" id="button1" type="submit">
</form>
```

When I submit the form I post it to the same page and I display the values the user had filled out. Only that now, instead of $fullname displaying the value of the variable $fullname, it displays the value of $_POST['fullname']. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem probably lies with `register_globals` in php's .ini file. Turn this off, restart php and it should be fixed.

Try this to check the setting at the moment of execution of the code:

```
echo ini_get("register_globals");
```

Comment: It's actually set to off. That's the first thing I checked.

Comment: try the ini_get method i added to see the value at the moment of executing your code.

Comment: yeah, it should be register_globals. I know of nothing else that produces this behavior,

Comment: Like I said, register_globals is off. http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/1341/clipa.jpg

Comment: It's possible to set it while running the code (`ini_set("register_globals", "true")`). That is why I advised to check it at runtime. Maybe some library of some sort is doing it without you noticing.

Comment: @dragon112: echo ini_get("register_globals") returns nothing, I suppose null. Is this correct?

Comment: what is your php's version? register_globals has been removed since version 5.4.0.

Comment: I'm running 5.2.6 on my localhost

Comment: if the ini_set returns nothing the value is `Off`. I can't explain what is happening or why. You should check any libraries or extra modules you added for code similar to what itsid posted.

Comment: I suspect there might have been another copy of php.ini on my system that was being called. I upgraded PHP to the current version and the problem was solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

probably you have register_globals turned on which is something that has been advised against for years already :) see here for details: http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 1):

You must to set method="POST" attribute in form declaration. And may be you have register_globals option is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `php.ini` for the `register_globals` setting. It is most likely set to on, you should turn it off.

Comment: It's actually set to off. That's the first thing I checked.

Answer (score 1):

Well if register_superglobals is off then you are doing similar in your script

like

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $val) // or $_POST or $_GET
    $$key = $val;
```